# Java array reflection: isArray vs. instanceof

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Is there a preference or behavior difference between using:

```
if(obj.getClass().isArray()) {}
```

and

```
if(obj instanceof Object[]) {}
```

?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

In most cases, you should use the `instanceof` operator to test whether an object is an array.

Generally, you test an object's type before downcasting to a particular type which is known at compile time. For example, perhaps you wrote some code that can work with a `Integer[]` or an `int[]`. You'd want to guard your casts with `instanceof`:

```
if (obj instanceof Integer[]) {
    Integer[] array = (Integer[]) obj;
    /* Use the boxed array */
} else if (obj instanceof int[]) {
    int[] array = (int[]) obj;
    /* Use the primitive array */
} else ...
```

At the JVM level, the `instanceof` operator translates to a specific ["instanceof"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#instanceof) byte code, which is optimized in most JVM implementations.

In rarer cases, you might be using reflection to traverse an object graph of unknown types. In cases like this, the `isArray()` method can be helpful because you don't know the component type at compile time; you might, for example, be implementing some sort of serialization mechanism and be able to pass each component of the array to the same serialization method, regardless of type.

There are two special cases: null references and references to primitive arrays.

A null reference will cause `instanceof` to result `false`, while the `isArray` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Applied to a primitive array, the `instanceof` yields `false` unless the component type on the right-hand operand exactly matches the component type. In contrast, `isArray()` will return `true` for any component type.

Comment: Yeah, but how much difference is it going to make? That sounds like a micro-optimization to me.

Comment: It depends on the application, but I'd be surprised to find the difference large enough to be worth going out of your way for. But, since it's the conventional approach, you should have some special reason (like support for primitive arrays) to justify using the awkward, sub-optimal reflection.

Comment: @Dims If you are asserting that `obj instanceof int[]` yields `false` when you assign an `int[]` to `obj`, you are mistaken.

Comment: Sorry I meant that `obj instanceof Object[]` yields `false` if `Object obj = new int[7]`.

Comment: Right, in Java, primitive data types are not objects, and don't extend `java.lang.Object`, so that makes sense. But `instanceof` can still be used to test for primitive arrays.

Comment: If you need to know an object is a general array without having to test every type of primitive array, then getClass().isArray() is a better, less costly approach (in terms of code size) and probably more efficient in terms of operation time too.

Comment: -1: In general, since primitive arrays *are* arrays calling `isArray()` should be used. In the very *not general* special case of only having arrays of objects, `instanceof` provides a high performance alternative.

Comment: I [cannot generally back the claim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171137/521799) that `instanceof` (a thorough check including primitive types) is faster and thus better than `isArray()`

Comment: @280Z28 Couldn't agree less. The question is specifically about `Object[]`. Handling any kind of array is a special case, extremely rare relative to testing for a particular type. Testing for a particular type is done with `instanceof`, not with a special method. Do you wish for `isString()`, `isInputStream()`, `isConnection()`, `isInteger()`, ad infinitum methods on every class?

Comment: @erickson If you click edit, you'll see I added a more explicit comparison of the two methods inside of a `<-- -->` comment. If you edit the post to include a clearer explanation of the relative advantages of each method (perhaps by removing the `<--` and `-->`), I'll change my -1 to +1.

Answer (score 34):

In the latter case, if obj is null you won't get a NullPointerException but a false.

Answer (score 8):

If `obj` is of type `int[]` say, then that will have an array `Class` but not be an instance of `Object[]`. So what do you want to do with `obj`. If you are going to cast it, go with `instanceof`. If you are going to use reflection, then use `.getClass().isArray()`.

Answer (score 4):

`getClass().isArray()` is significantly slower on Sun Java 5 or 6 JRE than on IBM.

So much that using `clazz.getName().charAt(0) == '['` is faster on Sun JVM.

Comment: Do you have any statistics, a case study, or other evidence that you can link to?

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into an issue upgrading a Groovy application from JDK 5 to JDK 6.  Using `isArray()` failed in JDK6:

```
MissingMethodException:
No signature of sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl.isArray() ...
```

Changing to `instanceof Object[]` fixed this.

Comment: This makes no sense. `isArray` is a method of `Class`, not `Type`, so of course `GenericArrayTypeImpl` doesn't have that method. And `getClass` can never return a non-`Class` `Type`, so you (or Groovy??) must have done something wrong to get this, like assuming every `Type` is a `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever have a choice between a reflective solution and a non-reflective solution, never pick the reflective one (involving Class objects).  It's not that it's "Wrong" or anything, but anything involving reflection is generally less obvious and less clear.

Comment: Er, well, "instanceof" is a kind of reflection (or, at least, introspection) as well, but I get your point.

Comment: Also, it is generally slower.

Answer (score 2):

Java array reflection is for cases where you don't have an instance of the Class available to do "instanceof" on.  For example, if you're writing some sort of injection framework, that injects values into a new instance of a class, such as JPA does, then you need to use the isArray() functionality.

I blogged about this earlier in December.
http://blog.adamsbros.org/2010/12/08/java-array-reflection/

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in behavior that I can find between the two (other than the obvious null-case). As for which version to prefer, I would go with the second. It is the standard way of doing this in Java.

If it confuses readers of your code (because `String[] instanceof Object[]` is true), you may want to use the first to be more explicit if code reviewers keep asking about it.