# Object.isArray() is slow, is there a fast way to do that?

Tags: java, performance

In my application `obj.getClass().isArray()` is called very frequently and become the bottleneck of the app.
I want to check efficiently at run-time if an object is an array. 
Primitive array and object array should return true.
The way I can imagine is to `instanceof` all primtive arrays, but cannot handle types like int[][].  And the app is used as lib, so I cannot list all types.
Is there any clue for that?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but it's a nice addition to the discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219881/java-array-reflection-isarray-vs-instanceof

Comment: I think the question is why you have to call that method frequently? I'd hope that if there were a faster way, the JDK developers would base their implementation on it. If there isn't, you have to give more detail about the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Your `instanceof` reasoning is not entirely correct. `int[][] instanceof Object[]` yields `true` (just as `int[] instanceof Object`), so those cases are covered... Not sure if this is relevant to your actual problem domain, though (see Axel's comment).

Comment: What evidence have you that this method is slow? And how slow is it - what's the average nanosecond duration?

Comment: @Bohemian By JProfile sampling, this function takes more than 10% persent of CPU for all variables security checking. And I profile isArray() myself, it is mush slower than intanceof.

Comment: Please, back your claims, as [I cannot confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171137/521799) that `instanceof` checks are really much faster than `isArray()`. Note, profilers do not give accurate results here, as instrumentation introduces a significant measuring overhead!

Comment: Class.isArray() is a native method, and should be quite fast -- mostly just the call overhead.  Also, being a native method, it would be hard to profile.  `instanceof` might be a hair faster, or not -- it's more complex logic but probably less call overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A benchmark I've just done gave the following results:

```
{s instanceof Object[]} spends 44ms
{s.getClass().getName().charAt(0) == '['} spends 58ms
{s.getClass().isArray()} spends 303ms
```

Benchmark has been done using [Benchmark.java](http://pastebin.com/pskJ1tSy), called with [Main.java](http://pastebin.com/KbptdWaB).

---

After having discussed the use of a `final` variable in the above benchmark, see the new results using a local one:

```
{s instanceof Object[]} spends 83ms
{s.getClass().getName().charAt(0) == '['} spends 93ms
{s.getClass().isArray()} spends 354ms
```

Even if the durations are all a bit longer (interesting btw), their order has been preserved.

Benchmark.java has been then called with this new [Main.java](http://pastebin.com/nisMGtnP).

---

And using a primitive array called with this other [Main.java](http://pastebin.com/n5q8ZCyj):

```
{a instanceof int[]} spends 71ms
{a.getClass().getName().charAt(0) == '['} spends 82ms
{a.getClass().isArray()} spends 340ms
```

Still the same results order.

Comment: Can you post the benchmark code? I got the [opposite results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171137/521799)

Comment: @LukasEder [Benchmark.java](http://pastebin.com/pskJ1tSy) and [Main.java](http://pastebin.com/KbptdWaB). I've to say that it's a tool I developed on my own, so I hope there's no mistake in it. Do not hesitate to tell me if you noticed one though, maybe I did something wrong :)

Comment: Yes, I suspect that `boolean b = s instanceof Object[];` is optimised away by the compiler, as `s` is `final` and the above expression thus always evaluates to true...

Comment: @sp00m Looking at the first character of the class name was a clever thing to try.  I like it!

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot To be honest, this wasn't my idea but [@SebastienTardif's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1681141/1225328) :)

Comment: @sp00m too bad I can give only +1 :)

Comment: It won't matter much, but instead of using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you should probably be using `System.nanoTime()`...

Comment: Hmm, the edit is biasing the test, as you're creating a new array at every iteration. Besides, I'm still not sure if the compiler / JVM wouldn't optimise things, as the `instanceof` check is quite obviously still always true. And then, primitive type arrays aren't considered... Oh well, benchmarking... :-)

Comment: Note that it's critical, in this benchmark, to have `s` be declared Object and be set in some other routine (preferably somewhat obfuscated).  Eg, the other routine should have a `switch` setting the var with several different types, and pass in the `switch` variable from outside.

Comment: @HotLicks & LukasEder: Right, seemingly, I still must have got few things to learn about benchmarking ;) Do you think you could provide a "Main.java" illustrating a relevant benchmark (for my personal knowledge) in your both opinions? In parallel, is my Benchmark.java unbiased enough?

Comment: Your benchmark does not handle primitive arrays, which the OP clearly stated is a requirement.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that a JITC implementation might very likely cache the last class passed to `instanceof` at a given code location, and return the same result if it were passed again.  At the very least, any test should alternate 2-3 different classes through the `instanceof`.

Answer (score 8):

`isArray()` is the most efficient way to check if an object is an instance of an array at runtime. If the performance is a problem, you can use one of the following methods to address it:

- Refactor your code so array objects and non-array objects are handled separately, so the results of `isArray()` are known at compile time.
- Use local variables and/or arguments to cache the value of `isArray()` during an operation, so it only needs to be called once.

Comment: I agree with refactoring, but can anyone please back their claims that `isArray()` is so much slower than `instanceof`? I feel that caching the result might do more harm than solve problems here!

Comment: It seems your (unsubstantiated) claim that `usArray()` is fastest is wrong - see sp00n's answer. I do agree with suggestions though.

Comment: @LukasEder I've just edited, results seem to behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I conclude that you may be suffering from an interpretive mistake when investigating profiling results. Your profiler's method-level instrumentation might be heavily crippling `getClass()` and `isArray()` calls, while being unimpressed by `instanceof` expressions. In other words, you're probably measuring the measuring overhead of your profiler, here.

Besides, in a quick benchmark, I cannot back your claim. I've run the following, very silly test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int rep = 10000000;
        Object[] o = {
            null,
            1,
            "x",
            new Object[0],
            new Object[0][],
            new int[0],
            new int[0][]
        };

        // "Warmup" to avoid potential JVM startup overhead
        long x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkInstanceOf(o);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkIsArray(o);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkClassName(o);
        }

        // Actual test
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkInstanceOf(o);
        }

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkIsArray(o);
        }

        long t3 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
            x+=checkClassName(o);
        }

        long t4 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(t2 - t1);
        System.out.println(t3 - t2);
        System.out.println(t4 - t3);
    }

    private static int checkInstanceOf(Object[] o) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Object x : o) {
            if (x instanceof Object[]) i++;       // Perform some logic
            else if (x instanceof boolean[]) i++; // to keep the compiler or
            else if (x instanceof byte[]) i++;    // the JVM from optimising
            else if (x instanceof short[]) i++;   // this code away
            else if (x instanceof int[]) i++;
            else if (x instanceof long[]) i++;
            else if (x instanceof float[]) i++;
            else if (x instanceof double[]) i++;
            else if (x instanceof char[]) i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static int checkIsArray(Object[] o) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Object x : o) {
            if (x != null && x.getClass().isArray()) i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static int checkClassName(Object[] o) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Object x : o) {
            if (x != null && x.getClass().getName().charAt(0) == '[') i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
394433000 // instanceof
110655000 // getClass().isArray()
396039000 // getClass().getName().charAt(0) == '['
```

So you cannot *generally* claim `getClass().isArray()` to be slower than a thorough set of `instanceof` checks. Of course, there is a lot of different ways to rewrite my test, but you get the idea.

Comment: This benchmark is flawed.  It does not take account of JVM warmup.  (I wouldn't be surprised you would got opposite "results" by doing the tests in the other order ...)

Comment: @StephenC: Of course I had thought of that and tried both ways. I'll update with results...