# Cast Object to Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an Object which MIGHT be an array.  It can also be primitive, or a string. If it is an array, it can be an array of literally anything.

I have no problem figuring out if it is an array but I can't seem to cast it into anything that I can iterate through to get the values out of.

```
// o is an object and clazz is the class of the o
if (clazz == Array.class) {
            Class ofArray = o.getClass().getComponentType();
            String arrayType = ofArray.getName(); // 'Double' for my test case
            //ERROR: [D cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object 
            Object[] objects = (Object[]) o; 
    }
```

My background is in ruby and php (where it would just work) and the static typing is messing with my head. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This throws the error

```
[D cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object.
```

What am I missing?

```
if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) o;  
}
```

Comment: You can test an object to see if it's an array.  This question addresses that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219881/java-array-reflection-isarray-vs-instanceof  Then you can cast is safely and iterate over it.

Comment: so why doesn't the cast in my example work?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps that particular object wasn't an array.  `clazz == Array.class` perhaps let some non-array objects through.

Comment: hmm... stil not working even with the alternate check for an array. See the updated question.

Comment: Try running it in the debugger, pause on that line, and see what type `o` actually is.

Comment: *Why* do you not know anything about it? What do you plan to do with the objects in the array? You probably want to investigate Java's [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) instead.

Comment: I'm parsing XML into useable java 'things.' I don't know anything about the array because I don't know anything about the XML being parsed.

Comment: This answer might be good for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5608477/1354879

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you do not want to make the switch for all primitive types you could do like this:

```
if (ofArray.isPrimitive()) {
    int length = Array.getLength(o);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Object obj = Array.get(o, i);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
else {
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) o;
    for (Object obj : objects) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you don't want to loop in two different places in your code use this method to convert the primitive arrays to an object array:

```
static Object[] convertToObjectArray(Object array) {
    Class ofArray = array.getClass().getComponentType();
    if (ofArray.isPrimitive()) {
        List ar = new ArrayList();
        int length = Array.getLength(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ar.add(Array.get(array, i));
        }
        return ar.toArray();
    }
    else {
        return (Object[]) array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but beware: an implicit boxing operation is happening here: `Array.get(o, i)` - in other words, the elements of type `int` are being converted to `Integer`, the elements of type `double` are being converted to `double`, and so on. This can be inefficient in the long run

Comment: Any idea when `java.lang.reflect.Array` was added to the JDK?  Is it available in 1.5 for example?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for arrays with elements that are sublcasses of `Object`:

```
if (clazz.isArray()) {
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) o;
    for (Object obj : objects)
        System.out.println(obj);
}
```

If you need to cast the array to an specific array type you could (ab)use `instanceof` but for, say, just printing the contents as strings, an `Object[]` suffices.

**UPDATE**

If the array is of primitive types, you have no option but to test for each one and cast to the correct type, `Object[]` won't work for this case - but there aren't *that* many primitive types in Java, so it won't be a gigantic switch :) . This is what I mean:

```
if (clazz.isArray()) {
    if (clazz.getComponentType().equals(double.class)) {
        double[] numbers = (double[]) o;
        for (double d : numbers)
            System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's still not working, check out the updated question.

Comment: In what line exactly is the error happening? the above code works flawlessly, the problem must be elsewhere

Comment: the error is happening on the cast. (2nd line) I've noticed that if I change my test array component type from 'double' to the corresponding wrapper 'Double' I don't get an error.

Comment: That's correct, this solution will not work for an array of primitives.

Comment: So how do I cast an Object that is actually an array of primitives to an array that I can iterate over?

Comment: is there really no better way than checking for each possible primitive? ... I see a large switch statement in my future =( I feel like there has to be a better way

Comment: @RyanEpp nope, there really isn't a better way. But cheer up, in Java there are only 8 primitive types ;)

Comment: @Ryan There are only 8 primitive types, so it's not _that_ bad.

Comment: Please rewrite this answer to better incorporate the "UPDATE" into the answer since the first section is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to know your `Object` is an array - you should also know the underlying type of the array elements. If your array elements are of primitive type, say `double`, you need to

```
double[] doubleArray = (double[]) o;
```

This won't work:

```
Object[] objects = (Object[]) o;
```

Comment: yes, but can I do this without knowing the type of primitive? (without writing a gigantic switch)

Comment: The way you are trying to use Java is very common in scripting languages like you mentioned: php, ruby. In statically typed languages like Java, this what you want can perhaps somehow even be achieved, but will be slow and is not considered as good coding.

Comment: You should try to outline your problem more generally so that we can give you general tips on how to deal with that in Java. Using Object type to pass arrays, Strings and other types to methods is NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot type cast an Array of primitives to an `Object[]`

```
if (clazz == Array.class) {
  Class ofArray = o.getClass().getComponentType();
  // String arrayType = ofArray.getName(); // 'Double' for my test case
  if (ofArray instanceof double.class)
    double[] doubles = (double[]) o;
  for (double d: doubles)
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

To create an `Object[]` without `instanceof` checks

```
if (!(o instanceof Object[])) {
  int len = Array.getLength(o);
  Object[] objects = new Object[len];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    objects[i] = Array.get (o, i);
  for (Object obj: objects)
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: The second version was exactly what I wanted! I don't need efficiency for debug output, just conciseness!