# How to determine obj can be used in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have try following code, but it return false.

```
package ro.idea.ex;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by roroco on 10/28/14.
 */
public class Ex {
    public <T> boolean canWorkInForLoop(T o) {
        return o instanceof Collection || o instanceof Iterable || o instanceof Array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2};
        Object r = new Ex().canWorkInForLoop(arr);
        System.out.println("r:" + r + "\t\t" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getFileName() + ":" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

**my question is:**

How to determine all obj which can be used in for loop, like new int[], instance of ArrayList and other obj?

Comment: Why do you want to do this for a raw `Object`?

Comment: How is this related to android ?

Comment: @user2336315 if android has solution but java hasn't, please tell me too

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you mean "Object r = ", it's only for quickly test in intellij idea with live template.

Comment: @user3370849 I mean that you have an `int[]` and you already know it is an array and can be used in a loop. Why do you want to *dynamically* do this with a raw `Object` (due to type-erasure) at run-time?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in this case, yes, i know what it is, but in a instance of Object[], i wanna select some one which can be used in for-loop

Comment: My suggestion is *don't*. Create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and preserve type information.

Comment: Why would you have an Object[] full of objects of different types? You clearly need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[]` is not an instance of `Array`.
use `o.getClass().isArray()` instead

more information can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219881/java-array-reflection-isarray-vs-instanceof)

Also, the `Collection` check is redundant since it extends `Iterable`, the `for each` construct is applicable to `Iterable`'s or arrays.

as explained in the comments, `java.lang.reflect.Array` is a utility class for creating/accessing arrays. It is **not** a base class for arrays.
arrays of objects extends `Object[]`, while primitive arrays extend `Object` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807748/249878)

Comment: i have some confused about o.getClass().isArray() but o is not instance of Array, why java is designed like that?

Comment: @user3370849 `java.lang.reflect.Array` is a utility class for introspection. Arrays in Java do not inherit from it.

Comment: @user3370849 Array is a class with static methods for handling arrays. object arrays extend Object[] and primitive arrays, i'm not sure what they extend if anything...

Comment: Look at the [javadoc for `java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) for more details - you'll see it's a utility class (all methods are static), not a class you are meant to instantiate. The name of the class is a tad confusing, I'll warrant, but the package name tells the story, that this is for reflection. It's not in `java.util`, after all.